# mitmproxy save both original and forwarded request and response

Tags: mitmproxy

What is a good way to save / write / log (request, response) pairs on both ends (client-facing, server-facing) of mitmproxy? That is, all 4 of:

- c->p: original request from the client
- p->c: final response to the client, possibly rewritten by the proxy
- p->s: request forwarded to the server and possibly rewritten by the proxy
- s->p: original response from the server

  ```
           c->p                         p->s
           original                     forwarded rewritten
           request                      request
         --------------------->        --------------> 
  client                         proxy                 server
         <---------------------        <--------------
           p->c                          s->p
           forwarded rewritten           original
           response                      response
  ```

As far as I can see, the `-w` flag (of `mitmdump`) only saves single (request, response) pairs, so either the original or the forwarded request / response are not saved (and possibly neither of those, only some intermediate stage, before / after other addons that modify request / response).

Thanks for help.

Comment: FWIW, mitmproxy generally stores the final representation of both request and response.

Comment: @MaximilianHils Thanks. To be sure, final is `p->s` and `p->c` in my example?

Comment: Yes, that's correct